# Distributed systems and choosing the nearest datacenter

Tags: database, request, distributed-system

I am wondering how to always direct request to the nearest data center. At the beginning I though about creating an app which calculates region based on IP address but then I realized that this is not useful because we still don't know how to make a call to the nearest app... Load balancer is only for routing request to machine which is least burdened.

Comment: What technology stack are you using for the client? And why do you want the nearest data centre - performance? Legal factors?

Comment: Latency issue. What do You mean by client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by using GoIP in your DNS servers, for example, you could use [powerdns](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-geoip/) in the case you want to host and maintain your own DNS servers.

An example from the docs of a zone:

```
domains:
- domain: geo.example.com
  ttl: 30
  records:
    geo.example.com:
      - soa: ns1.example.com hostmaster.example.com 2014090125 7200 3600 1209600 3600
      - ns: ns1.example.com
      - ns: ns2.example.com
      - mx: 10 mx.example.com
    fin.eu.service.geo.example.com:
      - a: 192.0.2.1
      - txt: hello world
      - aaaa: 2001:DB8::12:34DE:3
  services:
    service.geo.example.com: '%co.%cn.service.geo.example.com'
```

The way it works is by finding the country code from the IP making the requests (while resolving for `geo.example.com`) and then sending the defined records to that region.

From the example, if your users are in Finland and try to reach `geo.example.com` the returned IPv4 will be `192.0.2.1` and IPv6 `2001:DB8::12:34DE:3`

In case you are using AWS, you could use the [route53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo) service.

Another way is to use a CDN, for example, you could try [Cloudflare Load Balancing](https://www.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/) options.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is latency, geographical region is not the only factor affecting the latency incurred by reaching your server. A reasonable approach is to simply try all of your servers and see which one responds the fastest. This would buy you other things, including the ability to switch servers when one is down.